# Numpy / Flatten a list

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have create this of character

```
list1 = [['20']*3,['35']*2,['40']*4,['10']*2,['15']*3]
```

result :

```
[['20', '20', '20'], ['35', '35'], ['40', '40', '40', '40'], ['10', '10'], ['15', '15', '15']]
```

I can convert it into a single list using list comprehension

```
charlist = [x for sublist in list1 for x in sublist]
print(charlist)
['20', '20', '20', '35', '35', '40', '40', '40', '40', '10', '10', '15', '15', '15']
```

I was wondering how to do that with numpy

```
listNP=np.array(list1)
```

gives as output :

```
array([list(['20', '20', '20']), list(['35', '35']),
       list(['40', '40', '40', '40']), list(['10', '10']),
       list(['15', '15', '15'])], dtype=object)
```

The fact is that **listNP.flatten()** gives as an output the same result. Probably I missed a step when converting the list into an numpy array

Comment: why are you using a `numpy.ndarray` here at all? numpy arrays are fixed-size, true multidimesional arrays. They cannot be "jagged".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`hstack()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)

```
import numpy as np
list1 = [['20']*3,['35']*2,['40']*4,['10']*2,['15']*3]
flatlist = np.hstack(list1)

print(flatlist)
```

> ['20' '20' '20' '35' '35' '40' '40' '40' '40' '10' '10' '15' '15' '15']

In trying to construct your `ListNP` with `np.array` as you do in the OP, I got a warning about jagged arrays and having to use `dtype=object`, but letting `hstack` construct it directly doesn't evoke a warning (thanks @Michael Delgado in the comments)

Comment: what version are you using? I can do `np.hstack(list1)` just fine without a warning on 1.21.5.

Comment: oh - I do get this warning if running `np.hstack(np.array(list1))` but that's because it's trying to create  a ragged 2D array which it then ravels. but `np.hstack(list1)` works fine

Comment: @MichaelDelgado 1.20.3 from conda-forge.  Updating now to see if it persists.

Comment: yeah I think it's just `array(list1)` that's the issue, since it's not a regular shape. It assumes you want an array with 5 rows and variable-length columns. hstack on the other hand sees the outer list as the concat dim and the inner lists as the sub-arrays to be concatenated, so there's no problem.

Comment: But why torture yourself like this?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm always willing to learn some new tricks, so thanks for adding your answer!

Comment: @jonsca. Thanks for the endorsement. It takes a while to adjust to the differences in the thought process between effective vanilla python and numpy coding.

Answer (score 3):

You can bypass all the extra operations and use `np.repeat`:

```
>>> np.repeat(['20', '35', '40', '10', '15'], [3, 2, 4, 2, 3])
array(['20', '20', '20', '35', '35', '40', '40', '40', '40',
       '10', '10', '15', '15', '15'], dtype='<U2')
```

If you need `dtype=object`, make the first argument into an array first:

```
arr1 = np.array(['20', '35', '40', '10', '15'], dtype=object)
np.repeat(arr1, [3, 2, 4, 2, 3])
```